# Автобиографическая проза

Tags: литература

Подскажите, пожалуйста, авторов автобиографической прозы.

Comment: Автобиографическая - т.е. автор пишет сам о себе? Или имеется в виду "биографическая", как например серия "Жизнь замечательных людей"?

Answer (score 1):

Практически у любого известного писателя есть автобиографические произведения. Не буду называть конкретные вещи, а то, судя по вопросу, Вы не знакомы ни с одним русским классиком, что, простите, стыдно.
Советую познакомиться с творчеством Толстого, Горького, из современных - например, Крапивина (у него много автобиографических вещей, а каких - читайте сами, оно того стоит).